# postgresql_adapter error running rails scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Following the railstutorial instructions [here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app) I am getting the error:

> /home/devname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:675:in `rescue in connect': FATAL:  role "devname" does not exist

I also get this if I try "rails console development".

Here is my database.yml (minus comments):

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
 database: db/production.sqlite3
```

and my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'   

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.5'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end
```

I am at a loss, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Add username, password to your yml file and try connecting to sqlite console using that. Looks like some permissions issue.

Comment: You could also try to stop spring `bin/spring stop` to make sure that the app is using the correct configuration.

Comment: @lest - that did it!  thank you.  not sure what to do going forward, tho. how do I tell spring how to use development?  TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your app in development mode

```
rails server -e development
```